# How to get "Other Member's Profile"?

Tags: linkedin-api

The LinkedIn Profile API docs say you can retrieve [other member's profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin/consumer/context#retrieve-other-members-profile).

> To retrieve another member's profile, you will need access to the Person ID, available only via certain limited access APIs and subject to member privacy settings.

What is meant by these "limited access APIs". I cannot find any further information on this, and how to actually use this functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Clamsmash Nope, no one seems to know, and LinkedIn support doesn't know either/directs everyone to StackOverflow...

Answer (score 2):

Managed to figure this one out!

Your app needs the r_liteprofile or r_basicprofile permission:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api

There is also a r_fullprofile but you need to partner with LinkedIn for that.

To retrieve r_basicprofile data, here is what I do (assuming you have the OAuth token):

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people?ids=List((id:zGkuWDCmZX),(id:Ehhkpj-Cw7))
```

With the id being the characters after the urn:

```
urn:li:person:[these characters]
```

Comment: How do you obtain someones "urn:li:person:[these characters]" ?

Comment: You enumerate the shares: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api

And then you enumerate the comments / likes for each share. These records will contain the person id / urn.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/network-update-social-actions#retrieve-comments-on-shares

Comment: Ok, so this way you can get profile data for the people who liked/commented a share of "me"? It's better than I could before, but do you know a way to retrieve profile data from all of my connections or something? Thanks anyway!